# Read multiple parquet file at once and use it join query - Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive

I am having a full outer join query where i need to read multiple files at a time. Query is working fine for single parquet file.

```
 spark.sql("select target_table.*,lkp.account FROM parquet.`hdfs://gcgprod/data/work/hive/db/table/process_date=20221220/part-00886-6ba5c0ad97ba.c000` as target_table Full OUTER JOIN db.table_ref lkp ON target_table.chd_account_number = lkp.account")
```

But need help in reading multiple files at a time for better performance. I tried below query, but did not work

```
spark.sql("select target_table.*,lkp.account FROM parquet.`hdfs://gcgprod/data/work/hive/db/table/process_date=20221220/part-00886-6ba5c0ad97ba.c000`,parquet.`hdfs://gcgprod/data/work/hive/db/table/process_date=20221220/part-00887-6ba5c0ad97ba.c000` as target_table Full OUTER JOIN db.table_ref lkp ON target_table.chd_account_number = lkp.account")
```